# External USB Fingerprint Reader for Pre-boot Authentication for Dell Laptop

Tags: authentication, usb, fingerprint-reader

My company just purchased several Dell Latitude E6500 laptops with docking stations and external monitors.  These laptops have a fingerprint scanner located next to the keyboard.

DOCKED users who prefer to use the included fingerprint scanner for pre-boot authentication are forced to open their laptop in order to access the scanner.  This is an inconvenience when the laptop is docked.

We are looking for an external, usb fingerprint scanner, that will work with the current preboot authentication setup.  I assume that this scanner would have to access the existing credentials for authentication....wherever they are stored.

So we would require something that would work PRE-BOOT, use the existing credentials, and not interfere with usage when the machine was not docked, such as when the laptop is being used at home.

Does anyone have experience with this scenario?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a specific USB fingerprint reader Dell sells with that exact model of laptop made by 'UPEK' - it support a pre-boot environment too. Have a look on the Dell site ([HERE](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/products/Security_and_Protection/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&cs=19&sku=A2277372)) or call them, they're not expensive.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I dont know why this hasnt turned up in my Google searches.  I am going to leave the question up for a bit longer in order to have some cost comparison.  Thank you!

Comment: Microsoft used to sell one, Lenovo do too but you really need the BIOS on your machines to play ball and given the one I suggested is sold as an accessory for your specific machine and pointedly says it supports pre-boot I think you'll struggle finding anything else that works as needed and is much cheaper.

Comment: Good point and thank you Chopper2!  Question answered.

Answer (score 0):

It is very safe and convenient device for security instead of password that is vulnerable to fraud and is hard to remember.
Use Hamster with your choice of compatible biometric software for authentication, identification and verification functions that let your fingerprints act like digital passwords that cannot be lost, forgotten or stolen.

**Company Profile :-**
    Tutis Technologies, listed on the BSE, is a pioneer in the field of Biometric software solutions in India for access control and time attendance.  A BSE listed company, Tutis aims at introducing not just the technological innovation and prowess but a range of biometric products to customize & redefine workspaces through the best office automation and security solutions.

[**USB Fingerprint Scanner**](http://www.tutistech.in/fingerprint_scanner_usb.html)